# Copy based on last modified date of files

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I want to copy from below source  dir to the desired destination as shown below.

Source dir:

```
--Dummy
----dirA (contain files last modified 2/7/2015)
----dirB (contain files last modified 3/7/2015)
----dirC (contain files last modified 18/7/2015)
----dirD (contain files last modified 18/7/2015)
----dirE (contain files last modified 2/7/2015)
```

each `dir` above in Dummy contain files with specific last modified date

Destination dir suppose to looks like this:

```
--Dummy2015-07-2
----dirA (contain files last modified 2/7/2015)
----dirE (contain files last modified 2/7/2015)

--Dummy2015-07-3
----dirB (contain files last modified 3/7/2015)

--Dummy2015-07-18
----dirC (contain files last modified 18/7/2015)
----dirD (contain files last modified 18/7/2015)
```

so far, by referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777466/copying-files-and-creating-new-folders-based-on-creationdate), i managed to come out something like this:

```
$sourcePath = 'c:/dummy'
$destPath = 'e:/dummy'  

Get-ChildItem -recurse -Path $sourcePath | Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | 
 Foreach-Object{
     $folder = New-Item -Path "$($destPath)$($_.Name)" -ItemType Directory -Force
     $_.Group | Where-Object { -not (Test-Path "$($folder.FullName)\$($_.Name)") } | Copy-Item -Destination $folder.FullName 
}
```

but the above code directly copy the files within the dir of source dummy which make destination becomes like this:

```
--Dummy2015-07-2
----(all files from dirA & dir E)

--Dummy2015-07-3
----(all files from dirB)

--Dummy2015-07-18
----(all files from dirC & dirD)
```

(if possible, would like to do this using robocopy)

Answer (score 0):

Does dirA contain only files modified on 2015.07.02? Or does it contain files modified before that? In my answer, I assume the prior. I will also assume each folder only has files, or has folders that you want to associate with that same folder (i.e. you will not move them out of their parent folder).

Below is the code that should work. Fill in the first 2 variables.
And hey, it uses `robocopy` ! :)

```
$PathToRootOfDummy = "C:\path\to\dummy\root"
$PathToReplacementPrefix = "C:\path\to\dummy_new-" # date goes after the '-'

Get-ChildItem $PathToRootOfDummy | Where-Object {$_.PSISContainer -eq $true} | ForEach-Object {
    $nf = "$PathToReplacementPrefix$($(Get-ChildItem -Path $PathToRootOfDummy\$($_.Name) | Where { ! $_.PSIsContainer} )[0].LastWriteTime.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd"))"
    mkdir $nf
    robocopy -s -e $PathToRootOfDummy\$_ $nf
}
```

Comment: Although... I would recommend using `Copy-Item` instead, since we are doing this in `Powershell` anyway.